# SAS: Export a string containing a comma to a single cell within a CSV

Tags: csv, sas, escaping

I have a footnote which lists items using a comma.  The output needs to be sent to a .csv.  Because a .csv is comma delimited, the items of the list are output into different cells when opened in Excel.  How does one escape a comma when exporting to .csv?

For example,

```
ods csvall file = "test.csv";

title 'The first seven letters of the alphabet.';
data test;
  input x $ ;

  datalines;
  a 
  B 
  c 
  D 
  e 
  F 
  G 
  ;
run;

footnote 'Observe that the letters a, c, and e are lowercase.';
proc print data = test;
run;

ods csvall close;
```

I have tried using `ods escapechar "\";` to define an escape symbol and changing the footnote to

```
footnote 'Observe that the letters a\, c\, and e are lowercase.';
```

but this does not work.  It may be that `csvall` is not part of ODS.  Beyond this, though, I'm not sure what else to try.

This is the text in the file generated by the above code:

```
 The first seven letters of the alphabet.
 "Obs","x"
 "1","a"
 "2","B"
 "3","c"
 "4","D"
 "5","e"
 "6","F"
 "7","G"
 Observe that the letters a, c, and e are lowercase.
```

UPDATE: Reconsidering my question in light of responses, the division of the footnote into difference cells is not due to SAS.  It is due to Excel when the CSV is imported.  However, I do not think there is a way to automatically override this behavior.

Comment: Do you need to use `ods csvall` to do this or are you open to a pure data step solution?

Comment: Did you just try adding the quotes in the strings you are sending. `FOOTNOTE '"list a,b,c"';`

Answer (score 1):

If you add single quotes to the text of footnote then the commas will be quoted and can be read back into field1.

```
ods csvall file = "~/test.csv";
title 'The first seven letters of the alphabet.';
data test;
  input x $ ;
  datalines;
  a 
  B 
  c 
  D 
  e 
  F 
  G 
  ;
run;

footnote "'Observe that the letters a, c, and e are lowercase.'";
proc print data = test;
   run;
ods csvall close;


data _null_;
   infile "~/test.csv" dsd missover;
   length field1-field2 $60.;
   input (field:)(:);
   put (field:)(=);
   run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume your goal is to produce a file containing text that looks like this:

```
 "The first seven letters of the alphabet."
 "Obs","x"
 "1","a"
 "2","B"
 "3","c"
 "4","D"
 "5","e"
 "6","F"
 "7","G"
 "Observe that the letters a, c, and e are lowercase."
```

This should behave the way you are expecting - the commas inside the quoted text of the footer should not be interpreted as field separators by most programs.

I would suggest doing this using a data step rather than `ods csvall`, as it is relatively simple to do:

```
data _null_;
    file "/tmp/test2.csv" dsd;
    set test end = eof;
    if _n_ = 1 then put '"The first seven letters of the alphabet."';
    put _n_ x;
    if eof then put '"Observe that the letters a, c, and e are lowercase."';
run;
```

N.B. this will only add quotes around character variables if they contain commas or embedded quotes (which get promoted to double quotes), and you have to add the quotes around string literals yourself.